# Spring boot Cron Job not running on Kubernetes pod while running fine on local machine

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, cron

I have spring boot cron job like

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* */10 * * * *", zone = "IST")
@SchedulerLock(name = "<cron_name>", lockAtLeastFor = "4H", lockAtMostFor = "4H")
```

It is working fine on my local machine but suddently it stopped working on kubernetes pod. I wanted to know how can I debug to find the root cause of the issue. Please suggest.

Comment: did you check if a node is holding the lock but it has been terminated?

Comment: Yes. I checked my SHEDLOCK table and there is no entry made for any lock by any pod

Comment: Another strange thing i have observed that my class with cron job which is defined as a component is not getting scanned from @componentscan while another class in same folder is getting scanned and can be seen in logs as welll. Please suggest.